# Add `manifest.json` file to a Custom Wordpress Theme

Tags: wp-filesystem

I'm building a custom Wordpress theme and would like to add a `manifest.json` file so I can utilise the `​​"orientation": "portrait-primary"` that you can use with PWAs to lock the orientation on mobile to portrait.

Is it possible to add a `manifest.json` file to a Wordpress theme? Placing it in the root of the theme doesn't seem to work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just try it and then you can tell us? :)

Comment: @kero I did. It didn't work. Hence my question.